# iOS UITableView scrolling insets while filtering

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have some problem with UITableView scrolling. This is my simple screen where I have UITextField and UITableView with cells. When user type something in UITextField app filters list of items and reloads UITableView. And it is working as expected.

[image]

On the right screen you can see how UITableView looks when I scroll. Cells go under UITextField.

Let's assume I scrolled some cell and If I start to type something in UITextField I got list of filtered cells but some of them are under UITextField and I can't scroll them down.

[image]

Comment: Your tableview starts below the textfield or under the textfield?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the table's scroll offset doesn't change when you reload the table with new set of row data. You need to scroll back to top after reloading the table :

```
self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0),
                                   at: .top,
                                   animated: true)
```

and if you don't have a default place-holder cell to represent "No Matching Results" when there are no results and thus no cells to represent at Index (0,0) then add following condition before the above code to safeguard a crash:

```
guard cellResults.count > 0 else { return }
```

Comment: thank you, and what can happen with this code in two cases 1) there are no cells to display - would it crash? 2) what if I scroll down so that cell with index 0 is not presented anymore (and even not exist in memory) - should it work fine?

Comment: Yes, it would crash if there are no cells after your filter as this will try to find that cell to go to the location of the table. So you should add a check "guard cellDataRows.count > 0 else { return }" before that code. your 2nd point will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your UITextField contained on tableview header view? UITableView need scrolling with table or not?
If your need always show first cell when user input something in UITextField, i recommend it with RxSwift like this

```
textField
    .rx.text
    .orEmpty
    .debounce(0.1, scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
    .distinctUntilChanged()
    .subscribe(onNext: { [unowned self] query in
        //TODO: Do something with you table, for example 
        // self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0), at: .top, animated: true)
        // or update tableView. 
    })
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Comment: UITextField in not part of TableView. I think that adding RxSwift just to fix scrolling is overmuch

Comment: Yes, you can also use func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool with UITextFieldDelegate